# Require payment to update firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am developing a website that has a booking option. Users can look at the availability on my calendar and pay for a timeslot.

Here is my concern: Let's suppose the website uses PayPal, and I get verification for when the payment goes through... then the website will populate the database with the clients booking information and close that time slot on the schedule. Now, what if I were to just send information to the database. Suppose I modify the code on the client side and just send booking info to the database. Nothing is stored in the database to authenticate this update and so an appointment could be booked without payment. I believe this is possible and so I was wondering how I could secure it as to prevent this from happening.

I know this is a long question, but I really hope you understand what I am asking. If you have any suggestions please let me know!

Comment: I think that is normally done with authentication and authorization, if firebase supports that, it should be well written in their docs, but I don't know that product.  /edit: just found this on the more-info link on Stackoverflow for the firebase tag: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ - It's perhaps worth you also click on the firebase tag and the "learn more..." link, you might find soemthing valueable in the community edited firebase section of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any security should always be done on the server. In the case where you have the client code write directly to the Firebase Realtime Database, you'll rely on security rules.

Typically you'll write a record about each verified payment into the database. E.g.

```
payments
   user1: 15
   user5: 25
```

The `user1` and `user5` keys above are the IDs of the users whose payment you recorded. Your users get this ID from Firebase Authentication.

*Note that this write operation should be performed by a trusted our, so typically you yourself, a script that runs on a server you control, or on Cloud Functions.*

Then when a user tries to write a booking to the database (say in `/bookings/book123`) you only allow the write if there is a payment from that user:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "bookings": {
      "$bookingid": {
        ".write": "root.child('payments').child(auth.uid).val() > 10"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `auth.uid` is the ID of the user performing the write. Firebase ensures that this is the actual user, and cannot be spoofed by someone (unless they know your Firebase Authentication private keys). The rules above this only allow a write from a user if they have a payment (or of more than `10`).

Note that this is just a simple example. You may want to instead track payment/transaction IDs (from Paypal), and use those to synchronize up with writing of a booking with the receipt of a payment.